# Updatable and insertable views in Entity Framework Core 6/7

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is is possible to have mapped view in Entity Framework Core that would work as a normal table so that I can insert into it and update rows?

I tried this one https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20013
but I can't insert, only update works. Maybe in newer versions of EF Core that feature was added?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv That article doesn't discuss [updatable-views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/modify-data-through-a-view?view=sql-server-ver16) at all.

Comment: @Dai, it will allow edit View, even EFCore currently do not support that.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv EF6 and EFCore work fine with DML-to-`VIEW`, you just need to trick EF/EFCore into thinking the View represents an Entity (so it isn't exactly trivial, and means EF won't treat a VIEW of another Entity as the same thing, so there are plenty of things to take into consideration).

Comment: What's your view code?

Comment: The rules for create/update/delete to views are entirely dictated by the database engine. EF has no choice in the matter. That said, when asking questions about code, please add the code to the question, don't link to an (always transient) external source. In other words, ask questions as a [mre].

Comment: Could you post the update related codes?